# Combining Entries in an ArrayList with all same Attributes Except for 1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have two access database tables: one called trainers and one called trainerplan. I need to be able to query this database from my c# application in visual studio 2010 and display it. I cannot display the trainers multiple times; I have to display them once and then at the end, display all of the trainerplans they provide.

I can display all the trainers no problem. The problem I have is only display the trainer once with all of their trainer plans at the end. Right now, I am saving all it all into an arraylist.

Here is the query from the database that shows all of the trainers and their plans:

[image]

Here is how I need it to look in the application:

[image]

I have thought about creating a separate array for just the plans. I would have it check to see if the names are the same and if so, add those plans together. But I'm not sure if that's the right way to go nor really how to do that. I'm not even sure what to search for to get some ideas.

EDIT:

Here is the trainer table

[image]

Here is the trainer plan table

[image]

Comment: What does your c# code looks like :-) ?

Comment: FYI, why are you using an `ArrayList`? It's obsolete.

Comment: @John Saunders I was unaware of adding a tag in my title. Not sure how that happened. As for arraylists, the problem with school is that they teach you out of date stuff. I know list objects are what I should be using, but unfortunately, we have yet to be taught that in school or at least in the course I am in

Comment: @Jens Kloster. I'm not sure how I could provide just parts of the code to show what I am doing. I think there is a way to just query the tables and have it combine the column that is the same, which in this case would be planID. I have seen concatRelated for sql, but haven't been able to get it to work yet.

Comment: If your instructors take off points for using `List<T>`, then you should tell us which school you're at so that all can avoid it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders  lol. I go to Purdue. It's not that I lose points for using them, it's that I haven't learned them, so it makes it difficult to use something you don't know how to do.

Comment: First of all, your instructor should be ashamed of himself. Be sure to tell him we are now all ridiculing him. Second of all, there's no reason that the students can't be smarter than the teachers. Hint: [`List<T> class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your key to link between those tables names TrainerID and the following SQL Query should work, then you don't have to separate the querying.

```
SELECT MAX(t.FirstName) AS FirstName,
       MAX(t.LastName) AS LastName,
       MAX(t.Phone) AS Phone,
       MAX(t.[Hours]) AS [Hours],
       ( SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), tp.PlanID) + ' ' 
           FROM trainerplan tp
          WHERE tp.TrainerID = t.ID
          ORDER BY tp.PlanID
            FOR XML PATH('') ) AS PlanID
FROM trainers t
GROUP BY t.TrainerID ;
```

Comment: The query gives me a "Syntax error in query expression" error in Access. It highlights on your second SELECT statement. What links those are tp.TrainerID = t.ID. I changed that in the query and still get the error. I'll provide screenshots of the two tables. Your sql statement is pretty complex for me. I was looking into the ConcatRelated function, but haven't been able to get it to work yet.

Comment: I forgot to ask which database you used. What's the error message you got?

Comment: I'm using Access and it provides me with terrible error messages. All it says is Syntax error in query expression SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), tp.PlanID) + ' ' FROM trainerplan tp WHERE tp.TrainerID = t.ID ORDER BY tp .PlanID FOR XML PATH('') )

Comment: Oh, sorry, this whole code works fine for MS SQL Server, I'm not sure if this will work with MS Access as well. The code **CONVERT(varchar(10), tp.PlanID)**, I want to convert PlanID from number to varchar(10), so you could replace it by Access syntax and then try again, but if PlanID is already string, then we don't have to convert it.

Comment: I just saw that I put space between dot and field name in this line **ORDER BY tp.PlanID** and I have edited it, did you fix that and try again?

Comment: Same error message. From everything I'm reading, it isn't possible just through sql. I'll need a c# function.

Comment: Yes, if you use MS Access database, then I think so. And it will be great if you use **List** instead of **ArrayList** ^^.